# Overload resolution between lvalue and rvalue reference parameter when user-defined conversion is required

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
struct S {
    S(int) {}
};
void f(const S&) { std::puts("const S&"); }
void f(S&&) { std::puts("S&&"); }
int main() {
    f(42);
}
```

It may be obvious, and [GCC and Clang agree](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/474864cfd3380ed0), that the `S&&` overload should be called, but my reading of the standard is that there is actually no rule requiring this to be the case!

Of course, you will say that the call to `f` has to initialize a temporary `S` object and that overload resolution prefers to bind an rvalue reference to an rvalue rather than binding an lvalue reference. However, this is what the standard *actually says* in [over.ics.rank]/(3.2):

> Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence `S2` if
>
> ...
>
> - `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings (11.6.3) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a *ref-qualifier*, and `S1` binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and `S2` binds an lvalue reference
>
> ...

Thus, this tiebreaker concerning lvalue and rvalue reference bindings only applies to *standard* conversion sequences. But a *user-defined* conversion sequence would be required in order to call either overload of `f` given the `int` argument. The rule for ranking user-defined conversion sequences is (3.3),

> User-defined conversion sequence `U1` is a better conversion sequence than another user-defined conversion sequence `U2` if they contain the same user-defined conversion function or constructor or they initialize the same class in an aggregate initialization and in either case the second standard conversion sequence of `U1` is better than the second standard conversion sequence of `U2`.

Clearly, both conversion sequences (to `const S&` and `S&&`) call the same constructor, so the second one could be better than the first if its second standard conversion is better than that of the first.  However, [over.ics.ref]/2 says:

> When a parameter of reference type is not bound directly to an argument expression, the conversion sequence is the one required to convert the argument expression to the referenced type according to 16.3.3.1. Conceptually, this conversion sequence corresponds to copy-initializing a temporary of the referenced type with the argument expression. Any difference in top-level cv-qualification is subsumed by the initialization and does not constitute a conversion.

Based on my reading of this, the implicit conversion sequence for `int` to `const S&` is identical to the user-defined conversion sequence for `int` to `const S`, which is simply a single user-defined conversion with the second standard conversion being the identity conversion; similarly, the implicit conversion sequence for `int` to `S&&` is identical to the user-defined conversion sequence for `int` to `S`, which is also a single user-defined conversion with the second standard conversion being the identity conversion.

Therefore, there's no textual basis for the "obvious" choice of the second overload... or is there one that I'm missing?

Comment: Hm... doesn't the binding to `const S&` require an additional qualification conversion? (Same if you had a `const S&&` overload.) I don't think this qualification is "top-level".

Comment: @KerrekSB the paragraph says: "the conversion *sequence* is the one required to convert the argument expression to the referenced type". Thus, whatever user-defined conversion sequence is required to convert `int` to `const S` (here, the cv-qualification _is_ top-level), the exact same user-defined conversion sequence (with the same overload resolution implications) is required to convert `int` to `const S&` --- so no, there isn't an extra qualification conversion.